# 100 gallon propane tank backup?

Tags: troubleshooting

I work at a school and the kitchen is supplied by a 100 gallon tank. I cannot run out, this would be bad. Is it possible for a company to install a secondary connection that would allow for the use of a 100 lb tank in an emergency? I am picturing a direct shutoff for both so isolation would be easy when switching feeds. Has anyone heard of this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a commercial property (a school), not a residential property.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess you meant to write 1000 gallons and 100 lbs, not 100 gallons and 100 lbs.

The "standard twin-tank approach" used for 200lb and smaller tanks where two tanks are used has a special valve that uses gas from one tank until it runs out, then switches to the other tank and raises a (usually red) signal that the "first tank" is empty. When the empty tank is replaced, a lever on the valve is switched to make the tank that was second, first, the signal retracts, and the new tank becomes the reserve until the next tank switch.

For 250 gallons and up (typically 250, 500, and 1000 - after 1000, multiple tanks again) A tank gauge is used and when the level is at or below 30% you call for a "non-emergency" refill if your supplier does not already have you on a regular delivery schedule that keeps the level from getting that low. If you happen to notice that it's down below 10% you call for an "emergency" refill because it's cheaper to pay extra for that than to have the lines purged when they get to refilling you after you run the tank all the way out, and also because "you can't run out."

Unless your use is highly variable (in which case you should check frequently to know where the tank level is) or your tank is woefully undersized (in which case you should get a second full size tank, or a larger tank) it's absurdly rare to "run out" on either a scheduled refill or a "call at 30%" plan.

So, what sort of reserve could you get if you could get a 100LB tank as a backup? 42 gallons, more or less. i.e. less than 5% of the 1000 gallon tank you likely meant, because "100 gallons" is not a typical tank size for propane delivery.

Answer (score 0):

We have a 500 gallon tank. We are on a automatic refill and have a remote monitored volume sensor on the unit.  The company that fills it is the third company we’ve tried in our area. Theses companies are very incompetent. At least once a year they miss a fill up. It is usually in the winter and leads to damage in our home.  We’ve been informed that there is no provision to have an emergency tank added to our system (buy the propane refill co) We are looking to have a qualified technician come and add an emergency tank on the line. Many people in our area have added one. They have it “T” ed to the line and valved and enclosed in a box with a vent to the outside. Apparently insurance companies don’t like these but they also don’t like the calls they get for damages as because of negligence. Good luck!

Comment: Considering that the OP was asking about a commercial property (a school), I don't think he has quite the latitude to ignore the rules and the insurance company's demands that you can (but probably shouldn't) as a home owner. You probably would be quite upset to discover someone at your kid's school was skirting the rules like that.